# How to use Classifier with ClassifierCompositeItemWriter?

Tags: spring, classification, spring-batch, itemwriter

have trouble implementing a ClassifierCompositeItemwriter...

I am reading a basic CSV File and i want to write them do a database.
Depending on the data (Name + Name1) either write it to a simple ItemWriter or use a compositeItemwriter (that writes to two different Tables)...

This is my : [ClassifierCompositeItemwriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) see > Error Message below

```
public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<MyObject> classifierCompositeItemWriter() {
ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<MyObject> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<MyObject>();
writer.setClassifier(new MySpecialClassifier());
return writer;
}
```

I tried to implement a Classifier using the [Classifier Interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/classify/Classifier.html)

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.classify.Classifier;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MySpecialClassifier implements Classifier<MyObject, ItemWriter<MyObject>> {

@Autowired
ItemWriter<MyObject> writer1;

@Autowired
ItemWriter<MyObject> writer2;

@Override
public ItemWriter<MyObject> classify(MyObject obj) {

    if (!obj.getName().isEmpty() && !obj.getName1().isEmpty()) {
        return writer1;
    } else {
        return writer2;
    }
}
}
```

Eclipse keeps telling me : 
setClassifier(Classifier>) in the type ClassifierCompositeItemWriter is not applicable for the arguments (MySpecialClassifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classifier should be like this:

```
public class MySpecialClassifier implements Classifier<MyObject, ItemWriter<? super MyObject>> {

    @Autowired
    ItemWriter<MyObject> writer1;

    @Autowired
    ItemWriter<MyObject> writer2;

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<MyObject> classify(MyObject obj) {

        if (!obj.getName().isEmpty() && !obj.getName1().isEmpty()) {
            return writer1;
        } else {
            return writer2;
        }
    }

}
```

The only difference is `implements Classifier<MyObject, ItemWriter<? super MyObject>>` instead of `implements Classifier<MyObject, ItemWriter<MyObject>>`.

This is because an item writer can not only write `MyObject` items but also items of a superclass of `MyObject`.

Comment: It Works ! Thank You very much... you made my day !

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Can we do the same for Mongo Writer?

Comment: @SanjayNaik yes you should be able to use the classifier with any writer.