# Conditional writer for spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I use spring boot and spring batch

```
public ItemWriter<T> writerOne(){
    ItemWriter<T> writer = new ItemWriter<T>();
    //your logic here
    return writer;
}

public ItemWriter<T> writerTwo(){
    ItemWriter<T> writer = new ItemWriter<T>();
    //your logic here
    return writer;
}

public CompositeItemWriter<T> compositeItemWriter(){
    CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
    writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(writerOne(),writerTwo()));
    return writer;
}
```

I read a cvs file, do a process and after need to call two writer...
Depending a field value, writerTwo must be called.

Is there any way to get this goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Classifier with ClassifierCompositeItemWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501152/how-to-use-classifier-with-classifiercompositeitemwriter)

Comment: no really i search to call writeOne and if (T.totalAmout > 45) to call also writerTwo.....

Comment: In that case you need a custom composite writer.