# Dynamically generate ItemWriter in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

My `itemReader` in spring batch transforms a csv record into `Consumer` object. This object contains a property `recordType` which is either insert or update.The file which my  `itemReader` transforms may contain mix of update and insert records. Now while writing in my `itemWriter` I need to transform the `Consumer` record either to `InsertConsumerRecordDTO` or `UpdateConsumerRecordDTO` based on the `recordType` property. This means I need either `UpdateCustomerItemWriter` or `InsertCustomerItemWriter` at run time .In short, the requirement I have is

```
if(record has insert)
 Transform `Consumer` object to `InsertCustomerDTO`
 use `InsertCustomerItemWriter` and make a REST call;
else
   Transform `Consumer` object to `UpdateCustomerDTO`
   use `UpdateCustomerItemWriter` and make a REST call
```

Is it possible to achieve this functionality with spring batch?

Comment: You can use a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` for that. The idea is to classify items based on a given criteria (the record type in your case) and to delegate the the write operation to the corresponding item writer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501152/how-to-use-classifier-with-classifiercompositeitemwriter.

Answer (score 0):

Each chunk-oriented step in Spring Batch can only have single `ItemWriter`.

You can implement a custom `ItemWriter` that accepts a mixed `List` (Spring Batch 4) or `Chunk` (Spring Batch 5) of `InsertConsumerRecordDTO` and `UpdateConsumerRecordDTO` that performs the right action for each, respectively.

If the two DTO classes should have a common base class, then you can use that as type for `List`/`Chunk`. Otherwise, you can use `Object`.