# spring batch flatfileitemwriter for multifile of large data

Tags: spring, file, writer

i use chunk for write files. i have two tables files and datas

config.java

```java
public ListItemReader<> reader(String fileName) {
    listItemReader = selectDataOfFileFromDB(fileName);
        ....
    return listItemReader;
}

public FlatFileItemWriter<> writer(fileName) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<> delegate = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<>
        .name(fileName+XXX)
        .resource(new FileSystemResource("/xxx/xxx/xxx/"+ fileName)).build();

    return delegate;
}

public Step xxxxStep(fileName) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("xxxxstep" + XXXX)
           .reader(reader(fileName))
           .writer(writer(fileName)).build();
}

@Bean
public Job xxxJob() {
    List<fileName> list = selectFileNameFromDB();

    JobBuilder xx = jobBuilderFactory.get("XXXXjob");
    SimpleJobBuilder a = null;

    a = xx.start(xxxxStep(list.get(0)));
    a.next(xxxxStep(list.get(1)))
    a.next(xxxxStep(list.get(2))
    a.next(xxxxStep(list.get(3))
    .....
    a.next(xxxxStep(list.get(n))
}
```

I can write data to each of file but it not smart. any other solution is?

I try the classifiercompositeitemwriter but not suitable!

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: Can you give some more information related to your requirement in terms of sample example.

Comment: i find the same problem this is the link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974458/spring-batch-writing-data-to-multiple-files-with-dynamic-file-name

Comment: my solution has a problem is that all data in the memory at once.. i try to customer the multiresourceitemwriter. maybe can do it

Comment: If it is the same problem then the solution should work. If it isn't then don't point to it and properly describe your issue, you only told what (according to  you) doesn't work. You haven't described what you want to achieve.